# How to vectorize <x(t-lag), y(t)> for two similar shaped numpy arrays?

Tags: python, numpy

I have two numpy arrays of the same dimensions `x` and `y`. I would like to calculate the <x(t-lag>, y(t)> as follows for different values of lag. The following code works by I am wondering if there is a vectorized implementation that could be faster.

```
def foo(x, y, lags):
    T = x.shape[0]
    res_list = []
    for lag in lags:
        res_list.append(np.mean(x[lag:]*y[:(T - lag)]))
    return res_list


if __name__ == '__main__':
    T = 1000
    N = 10
    lags = np.arange(0, 40)
    x = np.random.randn(T, N)
    y = np.random.randn(T, N)
    res = foo(x, y, lags)
    print("done")
```

Comment: With expressions like `x[lag:]` you can't avoid iteration on `lags`.  `lag` in the slice has to be scalar.  Sometimes it's possible to look at that slicing for multple `lag` values and identify a pattern that can be expressed as a whole-array operation.  For example a upper or lower triangle,  To me at least, 'numpy vectorization'  is often a visual process, looking at the task in top-down way.  Sorry if that's too hand-wavy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is somewhat faster if you use einsum to avoid creating the large intermediate array:

```
def foo(x, y, lags):
    T = x.shape[0]
    res_list = []
    for lag in lags:
        res_list.append(np.einsum('ij,ij', x[lag:], y[:(T - lag)]) / x[lag:].size)
    return res_list
```

Timings:

```
Original
876 µs ± 10.1 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000 loops each)
Einsum
502 µs ± 2.81 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000 loops each)
```

This ends up being 43% faster.

I'm not sure if there is a fully vectorized solution.